# Setting a Splashscreen background image in VB.Net at run time

Tags: vb.net

I have a splash screen for my program that I want to have a background image that changes each time the program opens.
One way I saw to do this is to load it from a ImageList, but that has an maximum image size of 256x256.
The splash screen is 498 x 305, which means that I need to find something besides ImageList but hopefully with a similar ability to organize the images.
I did try just putting them into resources, but wasn't able to get it to set the background without erroring, and I'd prefer not to have 30 images cluttering the place up.

Comment: That begs the question, where do you think image lists keep their images?

Comment: Err, yeah, I see that now, not sure why I didn't notice before. My.Resources.splash1 works, but if I have 30 splash images, and a couple dozen other images (button icons, etc) in my resources how do I pull a splash image at random, and make sure I don't get one of the button icons? this is where ImageList would have been nice. If you know a way, type it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to pull it from the database.

```
BackgroundImage = My.Resources.splash1
```

works, but I couldn't find a good way to change it, other than to have a function with a huge select case in it.

```
Select Case iSplash
    Case 1
        Return My.Resources.splash1
    Case 2
        Return My.Resources.splash2
etc...
```

so my final solution, in case anyone else ever needs to do this:

```
Function splashimage(ByVal int As Integer) As System.Drawing.Image
    On Error GoTo sError

    Dim rSelect As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sSql As String = "Select * From tblSplashImages Where SplashID = " & int
    Dim ms As IO.MemoryStream
    Dim img As System.Drawing.Image
    img = Nothing

    With rSelect
        .Open(sSql, MyCn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
        If Not .EOF Then
            ms = New IO.MemoryStream(CType(.Fields!Data.Value, Byte()))
            img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
        Else
            img = My.Resources.tracks1
        End If
        .Close()
    End With

    Return img
sError:
    MsgBox(ErrorToString, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
End Function
```